# Set Theory Proofs - If then statements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I know this is a simple proof, but how do I go about address the if then statements in a set proof using element arguments? I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the right way to approach these proofs.

Here are two examples

Example #1
\begin{align}
&\text{Prove: for all sets}\,A\,\text{and}\,B\,\text{if}\,A \subseteq B\,\text{then}\,A \cup B \subseteq B \\
 &\text{by definition of Union}\,x \in A\,\text{or}\, x \in B\\
\end{align}

Example #2
\begin{align}
&\text{Prove: if}\,B \cap C \subseteq A,\,\text{then}\,(C-A)\cap(B-A)=\emptyset\\
\end{align}

I get stuck after this. What is the right way to approach the next step in addressing the if then statement of the proof?

Comment: I would start #1 with "Suppose $x$ is in $A \cup B$ and try to deduce from the hypothesis that $x$ must be in $B$,

Comment: In general, a proof of "set inclusion": $A \subseteq B$ must rely on the def: $A \subseteq B \text { iff  for every } x (x \in A \to x \in B)$

Comment: Thus, in order to prove $A \cup B \subseteq B$ you are working correctly: $x \in A \cup B$ means that  either $x ∈ A$ or $x ∈ B$. Under both cases (use hypotheses) $x \in B$.

Comment: You might find it useful to try the software at this webpage:  https://djvelleman.people.amherst.edu/pd.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly,
take example #1, the *if..then* statement is basically an implication, that is, you need to prove
$$
A \subseteq B \implies A \cup B \subseteq B
$$
therefore, you can just assume that the premise holds (i.e. $A \subseteq B$) and try to show the validity of the consequent (i.e. $A \cup B \subseteq B$).

In this case, the proof boils down to applying the definition of set inclusion and union, sketching the approach:

Assume that for all $x$, $x \in A \implies x \in B$ (that is, $A \subseteq B$, our *if..then* hypothesis)

then under this assumption we show $A \cup B \subseteq B$ by taking a generic element $y \in A \cup B$ and showing that $y \in B$ (again, by applying the definition of set inclusion)

This is trivial since by definition of set union $y \in A \vee y \in B$, and thus we distinguish the two cases

1. $y \in B$ trivially implies the consequent we are looking for (that is, exactly $y \in B$)
2. $y \in A$ implies $y \in B$ since our *if..then* hypothesis lets us infer so.

The approach for example #2 is essentially the same, you just need to apply other set theory definitions, such as intersection, set difference, complement.
I leave the details and the other example to you, hope this helps!

Comment: It should be "Assume that for  all $x$, $x\in A\implies x\in B$". Otherwise, it does not parse: either there is a variable missing in the quantifier, or else your premise is that something happens for all $x\in A$, but you are not telling us what that something is.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin true, that was a typo

Answer (score 0):

For your question, I believe its important to know the structure of your proof.
Proof: If (A\subset B), then (A\cup B) \subset B.
Since (A\subset B), every (x\in A) is in B).
To show (A\cup B \subset B), we must verify if (y\in A\cup B) then (y\in B).
Since (y\in A\cup B), we know (y\in A) or (y\in B).
If (y\in A) then we know (by A\subset B), (y\in B).
Thus, (y\in B).
Ergo, If (A\subset B), then (A\cup B) \subset B.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).